# How can we get IO utilization for Process by Process ID using /proc directory?

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system

[image: iostat screenshot]

I need to IO utilization for Process by Process ID without using any tool like iostat,iotop etc.

Can any please help me to get IO utilization using info files using /proc/PID?

Thanks in ADV.

Comment: And why don't you want to use any of the standard tools for this?

Comment: Thanks ewwhite. I dont want to use any tool and i want to know the core process of calculating IO utilization of any process.

Comment: You could take a look at the source code for one or more of the tools to get this type of information.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the io stats by process from `proc`. The information is available under `/proc/[PID]/io`

The information is stored like this:

`cat /proc/2039/io`

```
rchar: 293898605
wchar: 63376205
syscr: 114996
syscw: 51573
read_bytes: 98484224
write_bytes: 29159424
cancelled_write_bytes: 8192
```

The definitions of the fields are:

> rchar: number of bytes the process read, using any read-like system call (from files, pipes, tty...).
>
> wchar: number of bytes the process wrote using any write-like system call.
>
> syscr: number of read-like system call invocations that the process performed.
>
> syscw: number of write-like system call invocations that the process performed.
>
> read_bytes: number of bytes the process directly read from disk.
>
> write_bytes: number of bytes the process originally dirtied in the page-cache (assuming they will go to disk later).
>
> cancelled_write_bytes: number of bytes the process "un-dirtied" - e.g. using an "ftruncate" call that truncated pages from the page-cache.

[source](http://haifux.org/lectures/254/alice_and_bob_in_io_land/node51.html)

For further information on `/proc/[pid]/io`, take a look at the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=HEAD) or this [Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633286/understanding-the-counters-in-proc-pid-io).

If you want to calculate the utilization you will also need stats from `/proc/diskstats`. The definition of the fields is defined in the [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats).

However as you can see `/proc/diskstats` users different metrics from `/proc/[PID]/io` which means you will need a lot of calculation to get utilization metrics. That is why I don't think it is a very fruitful idea to calculate these metrics manually.

Comment: Thanks knowhy,How can we get IO utilization(%) for Process by Process ID using cat /proc/2039/io?